# OPENQUERY returns different results depending on the position of the WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

```
Select count(*) 
FROM openquery([server], 'select * from EXTERN.View12') 
WHERE TYPE = 'Bedrijf'
```

vs.

```
Select count(*) 
FROM openquery([server], 'select * from EXTERN.View12 
                          WHERE TYPE = ''Bedrijf'' ')
```

The difference in the above queries is location of the where-clause.
In the first query, the where-clause is outside the `openquery`.
In he 2nd query, the where-clause is within the `openquery`.

What one expects is that both queries return the same number!

However, the 1st query returns 2653 and the 2nd returns 2557.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of the `TYPE` column? Are local and remote collations the same?

Comment: Please provide the view definition along with the definitions of  its underlying tables.

Comment: Also why are you using `OPENQUERY` anyway, why not just do `Select count(*) 
FROM [server].YourDB.EXTERN.View12 WHERE TYPE = 'Bedrijf'`

Comment: What value is the correct one: 2653 or 2557?

Comment: I cannot do a select directly.

The server is defined as a 'linked server' to an Oracle database.

If the select count(*) is run directly on the Oracle database, the number is 2656.

Comment: If select is done directly, then
Select * FROM ITRIS..EXTERN.VDIS_PERS 
returns an error: 
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ITRIS" returned an invalid column definition for table ""EXTERN"."VDIS_PERS"".

Comment: The datatype of TYPE is VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)

Comment: 2656 is an entirely new value. could it be that the values on the tables are changing between executions and that's the reason you get a different result?

Comment: Good question Ronaldo. But the answer is no. Tables are not updated or whatsoever.

Comment: Since none of the values from SQL Server is correct, I believe your problem is not why they differ depending of the position of the WHERE clause, but why SQL Server doesn't get the right value at all. I think the info mustaccio asked is going to get us closer the the answer. One more thing: when you answer someone's comment, you should mark the user with the @ character before the name, like @Ronaldo, so that the user is notified of your answer.

Comment: @Ronaldo, I have found another strange behaviour of the openquery function (but I do have a solution!). Consider the next 2 statements:

1: SELECT *  FROM openquery(ITRIS, 'select * from EXTERN.VDIS_PERS   ')
  WHERE RELATIECODE = '480042502'


2: SELECT *  FROM openquery(ITRIS, 'select * from EXTERN.VDIS_PERS  WHERE RELATIECODE = ''480042502'' ')

The 1st statement does NOT return a row, whereby the 2nd does return 1 row.

Comment: If the first query is changed to (order by clause added to select inside the openquery):

 SELECT *  FROM openquery(ITRIS, 'select * from EXTERN.VDIS_PERS  order by 1 ')
  WHERE RELATIECODE = '480042502'
This query will return 1 row.